# Exporting GeoTIFF to ArcGIS Online

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, export, arcgis-online

I would like to add TIFs to ArcGIS Online as a layer using QGIS.

An example is the ValleyNAI layer here: https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/U0vgiXgwLpyQDfbW/arcgis/rest/services/ValleyNAI/MapServer

As far as I can tell, they were able to add TIFs to the tile layer. However, I cannot seem to figure out how to do so using QGIS.

Comment: You want to add the layer to QGIS correct? Not upload from QGIS?

Comment: No, I want to use QGIS, since I do not have ArcGIS Pro, to put TIFs on ArcGIS Online.

Answer (score 0):

To add the images in **QGIS** use the  **WMTS** connection.

```
https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/U0vgiXgwLpyQDfbW/arcgis/rest/services/ValleyNAI/MapServer/WMTS?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMTS&version=1.0.0&cacheKey=bc0596e7e633e54b
```

[image]

Comment: I am sorry what I said was unclear. Rather than adding them TO QGIS, I want to be able to upload TIFs to ArcGIS Online.

It appears that one can do it by publishing tile layers online.

Is there a way to do so using QGIS since I do not have ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: @Tim do you have an ArcGIS online account? you most likely need that to upload using ArcGIS Online. Not sure if you can create via QGIS

Comment: Yes, I do. I tried to upload directly a TIF, but ArcGIS Online does not support the format. :\ Here is what ArcGIS Online supports: https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/supported-items.htm